# PowerBI / PowerPivot - Data not aggregating by time frame

Tags: powerbi, powerpivot, dax

I have created a powerpivot model include in the image below.  I am trying to include the "IncurredLoss" value and have it sliced by time.  Written Premium is in the fact table and is displaying correctly.  I am aiming for IncurredLoss to display in a similar fashion

I have tried the following solutions:

- Add new related column: Related(LossSummary[IncurredLoss]).  Result: No data
- DAX Summary Measure: =CALCULATE(SUM(LossSummary[IncurredLoss])).  Result: Sum of everything in LossSummary[IncurredLoss] (not time sliced)
- Simply adding the Incurred Loss column to the Pivot Table panel.  Result: Sum of everything in LossSummary[IncurredLoss] (not time sliced)

A few other notes:

- LossKey joins LossSummary to PolicyPremiumFact
- Reportdate joins PolicyPremiumFact to the Calendar.
- There is 1 row in LossSummary per date and Policy.  LossKey contains this information and is the PK on that table.

Any ideas, clarifications or pointers are most certainly welcome.  Thank you!

[image: PowerPivot Model]

[image: Output]

[image: PowerPivot Panels]

Answer (score 1):

The related column should work. I was able to get it to work in both Excel 2016 and Power BI Desktop. Rather than bombarding you with questions, I'll try and walk through how I would troubleshoot further, in the hopes it gets you to a solution faster:

First, check the PolicyPremiumFact table inside Power Pivot and see if the IncurredLossRelated field is blank or not. If it is consistently blank, then the related column isn't working. The primary reason the related column wouldn't work is if there's a problem with your relationships. Things I would check:

1. Ensure that the relationships are between the fields you think they are between (i.e. you didn't accidentally join LossKey in one table to a different field in the other table)
2. Ensure that the joined fields contain the same data (i.e. you didn't call a field LossKey, but in fact, it isn't the LossKey at all)
3. Ensure that the joined fields are the same data type in Power Pivot (this is most common with dates: e.g. joining a text field that looks like a date to an actual date field may work, but not act as expected)

If none of the above are the problem, it doesn't hurt to walk through your data for a given date in Power Pivot. E.g. filter your PolicyPremiumFact table to a specific date and look at the LossKeys. Then go the LossSummary table and filter to those LossKeys. Stepping through like this might reveal an oversight (e.g. maybe the LossKeys weren't fully loaded into your model).

If none of the above reveals anything, or if the related column is not blank inside Power Pivot, my suggestion would be to try a newer version of Excel (e.g. Excel 2016), or the most recent version of Power BI Desktop.

If the issue still occurs in the most recent version of Excel/Power BI Desktop, then there's something else going on with your data model that's impacting the RELATED calculation. If that's the case, it would be very helpful if you could mock up your file with sample data that reproduces the problem and share it.

One final suggestion I have is to consider restructuring your tables before they arrive in your data model. In your case, I'd recommend restructuring PolicyPremiumFact to include all the facts from LossSummary, rather than having a separate table joined to your primary fact table. This is what you're doing with the RELATED field to some extent, but it's cleaner to do before or as your data is imported into Power Pivot (e.g. using SQL or Power Query) rather than in DAX.

Hope some of this helps.